# Can I use SSIS to submit a file

Tags: web-services, ssis, attachment

I've been asked if we can supply a file to a customer via web services. We uses Scribe a lot for sending data to web services but I can't send attachments. Anyone know if I could do something like this with SSIS (or another tool):

This is a method that a client uses to upload purl updates.  This is a single file that is uploaded in a CSV format with the first row being the header.
The method expects five (5) parameters:

```
Parameters (1) a string that is the login name.
Parameters (2) a string that is used for the password.
Parameters (3) a string that is used to specify which application.
Parameters (4) a string that is the file name. This is used to identify a specific file upload.
Parameters (5) an array of bytes that is the content of the file.
Parameters (6) an integer that defines the length of the file upload. 
RETURNS an integer that will return the number of items successful uploaded or a negative number that returns an error.
Sample:
    //  Connect to the Web Service
    PurlService.ServiceFile     service   = new PurlService.ServiceFile();
    // Test the method
    string            login          = “mylogin”;
    string            password       = “mypassword”;
    string            application    = “FSI”;
    string            filename       = “myfilename.csv”;
    byte []           bytes          = new byte[file.ContentLength];
    file.InputStream.Read( bytes, 0, file.ContentLength)
    int               returnValue    = service.UploadFile(login, password, application, fileName, bytes, bytes.Length );    //  If successful, the returnValue will be a text message.
```

Answer (score 1):

SSIS provides access to the .NET libraries so if you can write it in a console app, you can do it in SSIS (I have an SSIS package that plays MP3s just to prove this point). The [Script Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141752.aspx) is how you will want to make your web service call. There is a built-in web service task but it's crap. The above code looks vaguely correct for a web service call although mine are all Windows Auth so I set credentials differently.

Workflow-wise, I'd expect your package to look something like a `Data Flow` to generate your CSV extract and then a Script Task to call your web service and then possibly a file task to archive the CSV or an Execute SQL Task to record the transmission details in a table.